# Array of hashes in loop, rewriting hash values during each iteration

Tags: ruby

I'm using a loop that changes hash values during each iteration. I'm then trying to push (add) the new hash values to an array at the end of each iteration.

```
# Array and hash to hold response
response = []
test_data = Hash.new    

# Array of search elements for loop
search = ["testOne", "testTwo", "testThree"]    

current_iteration = 0   

# Loop through search words and get data for each
search.each do |element| 

    test_data["Current element"] = element
    test_data["Current iteration"] = current_iteration

    response.push(test_data)
    current_iteration += 1
end
```

It seems that the array is only holding the hash values of the final iteration. Any tips on this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is because `Hash` object always hold unique keys, and keys hold the most latest updated values with it. Now inside the `each` method you were keep updating same keys as `"Current element"` and `"Current iteration"` for every iteration of through the array `search`. As I said above, keys inside a hash always holds the latest updated value, so your hash also holds the last iteration value.

Now, you are pushing the same `hash` object inside the array `response`, thus finally you got same 3 hashes inside the array `response`. What you want to achieve, to meet that you need to use [`Object#dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-dup).

Corrected code :

```
response = []
test_data = hash.new    

# array of search elements for loop
search = ["testone", "testtwo", "testthree"]    

current_iteration = 0   

# loop through search words and get data for each
search.each do |element| 

    test_data["current element"] = element
    test_data["current iteration"] = current_iteration

    response.push(test_data.dup)
    current_iteration += 1
end

response 
# => [{"current element"=>"testone", "current iteration"=>0},
#     {"current element"=>"testtwo", "current iteration"=>1},
#     {"current element"=>"testthree", "current iteration"=>2}]
```

Elegant way to do this :

```
search = ["testone", "testtwo", "testthree"]    

response = search.map.with_index do |element,index|
  {"current element" => element, "current iteration" => index}
end

response 
# => [{"current element"=>"testone", "current iteration"=>0},
#     {"current element"=>"testtwo", "current iteration"=>1},
#     {"current element"=>"testthree", "current iteration"=>2}]
```